# Issues with Disqus Single-sign on, no connection made

Tags: php, disqus

i am trying to implement disqus single sign on, but i cannot seem to make a connection, i set up a test page:

```
<?php
define('DISQUS_SECRET_KEY', 'mykey');
define('DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY', 'myotherkey');

$data = array(
    "username" => "Disqus Test",
    "url" => "http://disqus.com",
    "id" => "999",
    "avatar" => "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31679327/Screenshots/30v.png",
    "email" => "disqus-test@disqus.com"
);

function dsq_hmacsha1($data, $key) {
    $blocksize=64;
    $hashfunc='sha1';
    if (strlen($key)>$blocksize)
    $key=pack('H*', $hashfunc($key));
    $key=str_pad($key,$blocksize,chr(0x00));
    $ipad=str_repeat(chr(0x36),$blocksize);
    $opad=str_repeat(chr(0x5c),$blocksize);
    $hmac = pack('H*',$hashfunc(
    ($key^$opad).pack('H*',$hashfunc(
    ($key^$ipad).$data)
    )
    )
    );
return bin2hex($hmac);
}

$message = base64_encode(json_encode($data));
$timestamp = time();
$hmac = dsq_hmacsha1($message . ' ' . $timestamp, DISQUS_SECRET_KEY);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Site</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="disqus_thread"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_config = function() {
this.page.remote_auth_s3 = "<?php echo "$message $hmac $timestamp"; ?>";
this.page.api_key = "<?php echo DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY; ?>";
}

/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
var disqus_shortname = 'funkydic'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function() {
var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>

<?php echo "$message $hmac $timestamp"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I decode the payload, and it looks as it should, the issue seems to lie in the connection, even tho everything looks like its been setup as it should.

Any help is apriciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your actual code is fine, this is almost certainly either an application configuration error or an improperly-place javascript variable.

First step is to check out this document which goes over the most common issues: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1148640

Especially check to make sure the X-Disqus-Remote-Auth header makes it in the request.

If all those check out, post the full source code of the page including your public key (it only works on a domain you specify) and we can see if there's anything else wrong